# PHP script not echoing after foreach statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have tested several solutions but have been unsuccessful in finding the correct solution. I have tested increasing the memory available, using different loops such as while and foreach. I have looked over the code to see if I missed any brackets or braces with no success. Below is the code and what doesn't work is the echo statements after the foreach loop. Adding additional rows to the database are echoed correctly so I don't believe it is a memory issue.

```
echo <<<_END
<br>
<h3>View or Edit Contacts for $customerName</h3>
    <div id="contactList">
        <!-- Drop down list for customer select and update runs showCustomer.js when customer is selected-->
        <form>
            <select name="contacts" onchange="showContacts(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select a Contact to View:</option>
_END;

try {
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT contactID, contactTitle, contactLast FROM contacts"); 
$stmt2->execute();

//return option statement for each row of customers
    //while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()) {
    foreach($stmt2 as $row2){
        echo '<option value="'.$row2['contactID'].'">'.$row2['contactTitle']." ".$row2['contactLast']."</option><br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Finally Working";
    echo "<br>";
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: your `echoing` inside your `select`?

Comment: As also mentioned by @Phiter on [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486848/php-script-not-echoing-after-foreach-statement/34486872#comment56715719_34486872), you don't need `<br>` at the end of the `<option>`-s. You can remove it.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `</select>` right after the `foreach`.

Edit like so:

```
foreach($stmt2 as $row2){
        echo '<option value="'.$row2['contactID'].'">'.$row2['contactTitle']." ".$row2['contactLast']."</option><br>";
}
echo '</select>'; // added this line
echo "<br>";
echo "Finally Working";
echo "<br>";
```

And you'll see that it's `Finally Working`.

---

**Note:**
If you inspect the page you might see something like this:

```
<option value="1">Select a Contact to View:</option>
<option value="2">Some Option</option>
<br>
finally working
<br>
```

On my testes (firefox), the browser automatically added `</select>`, but only after `<br>Finally Working<br>`.

Comment: Just need to mention that he doesn't need to echo <br> after each option.